# Java getDeclaredConstructor fails with NoSuchMethodException from JUnit

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I have a base class, which uses reflection to create empty copy of concrete class using the following:

```
public IBase getEmptyCopy() {
   Class type = this.getClass();
   Constructor<?> ctor;
        try {
            ctor = type.getDeclaredConstructor();
            ctor.setAccessible(true);
            clonedObject =(Base) ctor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I've created a class called Test with the following main method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args)  {
....
ConcreteClass emptyInstance = (ConcreteClass) someInstance.getEmptyCopy();
}
```

All seem to work, however when I try to do the same in a JUnit test case:

```
@Test   
   public void test() {
    ....
        ConcreteClass emptyInstance = (ConcreteClass) someInstance.getEmptyCopy();
        }
```

I get an java.lang.NoSuchMethodException on the getDeclaredConstructor call.

can anyone explain what is the reason for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Paste your full class definition.

Comment: yep. Also the cloning method looks just like some sort of fragment since it does not actually have return statement... too few data to help :)

Comment: I found a breakthrough: the creation of SomeInstance uses initialization syntax, which apparently creates an anonymous class. Once I've removed the initialization syntax it works both in JUnit and in regular main.
So now the question is, is there some different handling of anonymous classes in JUnit?